# php output value does not match debugger value

Tags: php, getter-setter

So, I'd be OK (for now) with thinking that I misunderstand magic __get and __set in PHP. Fine.

But the output of this example is not only unexpected, it's also not matching what the debugger *says* is going to be output.

```
<?php
// put your code here
class Magic {
    public $a = 'A';
    public $x = 'X';
    protected $b = array("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C");
    protected $c = array(1,2,3);

    public function __get($v) {
        echo "$v,";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }
     public function set($var, $val) { 
        echo "$var: $val";
        $this->$var = $val;   
    }
}
$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";

echo $m->x;
?>
```

The output of this is:

b,c,A,B,C,X

Now, I set up XAMPP and NetBeans just to debug this ... when I put a breakpoint on

```
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
```

and hover over that $m->a, I see

(string) A

But that's not what gets output? The first character to get output is

b

What's going on? The debugger says that $m->a has a value of A, but when we echo it, it outputs b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ZCE question)

Line `echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";` means:

1. Get value of `$m->a`. It is `A`. As debugger shows you.
2. Get value of `$m->b`. You don't have **public** property `b`, so `__get` runs. It echoes `b,` (from line `echo "$v,";`) and returns `B`
3. Get value of `$m->c`. You don't have **public** property `c`, so `__get` runs. It echoes `c,` (from line `echo "$v,";`) and returns `C`.
4. Concatenate **returned** values ('A', 'B', 'C') with `,`.

So, before `echo`ing result of concatenating two `echo`s already done: `b,c,`. After that `A,B,C` string `echo`ed

Comment: Could be such a question ;) 

And your answer makes sense, of course (face/palm)